# AngularJS $location.search

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating an Ecommerce platform, and I have a list of products in JSON that I am reading from fine.  The way I want this to work is that I can put something like this:

```
{{products.products[parseInt(window.location.search)]}}
```

My current code:

```
product.controller('products', ['$http', '$location',
    function ($http, $location) {

        var store = this;


        console.log = $location.search();
        this.id = $location.search();

        store.products = [];
        $http.get('http://adambkeim.com/js/data.json').success(function (data) {
           store.products = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });

    }
]);
```

and then in the main page:

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="products as products">
        <h1 style="color: green;">{{products.products[products.id].name}}</h1>
        <p>{{products.products[0].desc}}</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="/products/products.html?id=0" role="button">Learn More</a>
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Right now, neither the parseInt or the window.location are even getting any values,  when I try to print to the console, it can't print out any content.

Comment: so what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: should really be using scope inside your controller instead of setting the product list on the controller itself

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, now you can do it like this:

```
$location.search().id
```